# Objective-C / iOS share documents to upload in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I'm doing an app like Dropbox and I need to know the difference between those two photos:

I want to upload the selected file in my server.

I want to my app appear here:

[image: photo1]

But it appears here:

[image]

How can I do to show my app with another apps like in the first photo??
**(PruebaMenu is my app)**

**EDIT**

This is my Documents Types:
[image: photo3]

**EDIT2**
Info.plist code:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>approv</string>
            <string>logoapp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Prueba</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
            <string>public.image</string>
            <string>public.video</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your app to show up in the first photo, your app must register for the type of files it supports. Your app's plist must contain a CFBundleDocumentTypes key and inside this array you declare the different file types that your app supports. See this Apple doc for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: I don't think "Bundle name" should be there. Can you post a picture or text of your CFBundleDocumentTypes key directly from inside your plist?